# How to get Activity's view?

Tags: java, android, android-view, android-alertdialog

I have the following method and I want to show a `Snackbar`. The problem is, I don't have my activity `view` and I don't know how to get it. In the code you'll see that `Snackbar view` is `viewInflate_setup` but it doesn't work. I know it doesn't work because this is the view from my `alertdialog` and not my current screen. I've tried getting the `root view` but then the `snackbar` is shown in the wrong place(Behind those three android buttons). How do I get my activty `View`?

```
public void confirmPassword(){
        final LayoutInflater inflateSetup = getLayoutInflater();
        final View viewInflate_setup = inflateSetup.inflate(R.layout.inflate_setup, null);

        AlertDialog.Builder alertSetup = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertSetup.setView(viewInflate_setup);
        final AlertDialog dialogSetup = alertSetup.create();
        dialogSetup.show();

        btnConfirmPassowod = (Button)viewInflate_setup.findViewById(R.id.btnConfirm);
        btnConfirmPassowod.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v) {
                System.out.println("User has clicked the [confirm] button");
                dialogSetup.setCancelable(false);
                edtPassword3 = (EditText)viewInflate_setup.findViewById(R.id.edtPassword3);
                SUpassword3 = edtPassword3.getText().toString();

                final ParseUser beforeConfirmPassword = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
                ParseUser.logInInBackground(beforeConfirmPassword.getUsername(), SUpassword3, new LogInCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseUser parseUser, ParseException e) {
                        if(e==null){
                            //password confirmed, go to next setup
                            System.out.println("Password [" +SUpassword3+ "] and user [" +beforeConfirmPassword.getUsername()+ "] confirmed, go to setup");
                            dialogSetup.dismiss();
                        }else{
                            //passwords don't match
                            System.out.println("Password don't match: [" +SUpassword3 + "] USER [" +beforeConfirmPassword.getUsername()+ "]");
                            Snackbar.make(viewInflate_setup, "Wrong password. Try again.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
                            dialogSetup.dismiss();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: In what type of class is this method?

Comment: I am assuming this is an activity in which you have written the function. In that case you can add an `android:id` attribute to the root layout of your activity.xml file and then use `findViewById(R.id.root_layout_id)` to get the view. You can also get the root view of your activity via `findViewById(android.R.id.content)`.

Comment: That's what I did @wanpanman. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only thing that you need is set an `id` of you root view and create an instance of it.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LineaLayout
  ...
  android:id="my_root">
  ...

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity**

```
private LinearLayout mRootView;
onCreate(...){
  ...
  mRootView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_root);
  ... 
}
```

And, in you alert dialog just create a snackbar like:

```
Snackbar.make(mRootView, "Wrong password. Try again.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("Action", null).show();
```

Comment: What about `mRootView = findViewById(android.R.id.content)`?

Comment: I didn't know that, man! it is really great. thanks!

Comment: All answers on this post works. Thanks all of you.

Answer (score 8):

well you can use `findViewById(android.R.id.content)` or `getWindow().getDecorView()` to get root view of your activity

i.e `Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Wrong password. Try again.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();` will do the job.