# How to pass the "View" of the main activity to a function

Tags: kotlin

I had a function in the main Activity that uses

val Nav: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation)

because view was not necesary due to setContentView()

but now I moved this function to another class to be called with global companion Object
So i need to pass it the view to activate it, since I have no View, just the setContentView()

How do I pass the view to this function?

Thank you

Comment: Can help to attach your code here as well?

Comment: Why not pass the navigation view itself? Seems like a convoluted design for some other class to have to start digging into your Activity's view hierarchy and extract views. Separation of concerns.

Answer (score 0):

Could this be an alternative formation of your question? [How to get Activity's view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38664192/how-to-get-activitys-view)

There an answer was given as

```
findViewById(android.R.id.content)
```

Worked for me (with Kotlin).

Guess you have managed to solve this issue already, but the question seemed too lonely to ignore.
Perhaps this will save someone else’s time later.